# How do I handle AWS EC2 when I am out of static IP addresses?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, ipv4

We have more servers than static IPV4 aws is allowing us to use.

This means that some of our servers will change IP when we change or restart our servers.

How can I handle this so that the DNS will always work? Do I just need to buy new IP addresses?

Comment: do you mean public ip addresses?

Comment: by default you get 5 elastic ip addresses per account, but you can try submitting a request to increase the limit

Comment: you could buy Elastic IP address and then assign it to your EC2 instance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the following options:

1. [Dynamic DNS.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-dns.html)
   The idea is that we have a special agent installed on EC2 instance, 
   that after each IP change sends it to DNS registry that updates DNS 
   record with new IP.
2. Service registry/discovery.
   We register our services in service registry/discovery. In this case we don't care about IPs, we care about their DNS names.
   When each service starts, it updates DNS record for it in the registry.
3. Have more static IPs :-)